# Google OAauth Public Cert/Key Rotation - Caching Public Certs

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

I am generating id_tokens for GCP Service Accounts and verifying those against Google public keys (and validating the payload) in my service. Public keys are here: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

I assume there are 2 keys so you can easily migrate during key rotation. However, there is no documentation about the rotation process or how often they do it.

I'm using this library to validate - https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php. This library stores the keys for 1 hour in the cache (AccessToken.php). This cannot be changed.

Theoretically then, you may be able to cache the old keys for up to an hour and wouldn't know it (assuming you cached right before both keys got rotated). This library does not respect Cache-Control header which Google recommends.

Question: is storing keys for an hour typically safe? I assume Google doesn't rotate both keys at the same time. And there is a window of time between when google stops using a key pair and rotates it. Is there documentation on this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a standard JWT library to me and you should also have the option to other PHP JWT libraries to do the same thing. The library downloads and caches a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) containing token signing public keys. This is safe since there are no secrets here.

When a JWT is received, the `kid` field from the JWT header is read. If this exists already in the cache, there is no new JWKS lookup. The cached public key is used to verify the JWT signature.

When the authorization server rotates its token signing key, it adds a new public key to the JWKS, with a new `kid`. The old entries will remain there for a while, eg a day or two, so that in-use tokens continue to validate.

When a JWT signed with the new key is received, the JWT library will find a new `kid` in the JWT header, so will do a new JWKS download, to get the new public key. Thus, renewal is seamless for applications.

My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/jwt-access-token-validation/) explains this in a visual way, to show how OAuth externalizes key management from applications, while also accounting for reliability.

Comment: The slight problem I think in that explanation is that an attacker can just send JWT's with random, but valid kid's, making you refetch certs all the time. Possibly leading to an outage if you are throttled. 

Adding the keys before deleting them makes sense for the authorization server. I just wanted to see if there is official documentation on this.

Comment: [RFC7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) is the definitive resource. In terms of the DoS threat you mention, a good library defends against that also. See this [cooldown duration setting](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/jwksRetriever.ts#L26) as one example.

Comment: The linked article by Gary is pretty good and will help beginners understand the basics. In Google Cloud, there are a number of factors that must also be considered when managing tokens (Assertions, OAuth and OIDC) and the services that accept, validate, and send tokens.